# How does Netlify CMS sort collections in their UI?

Tags: netlify-cms

I understand it's not currently possible to sort collections via the UI in Netlify CMS, but can someone tell me how it's currently sorting markdown files? I thought it was by filename at first, but that isn't 100% accurate.

Comment: For non coding questions, better to ask in https://community.netlify.com/c/netlify-platform/netlify-cms

Answer (score 0):

You can define [`sortableFields`](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/configuration-options/#sortablefields) in the `config.yml`.
That will let you sort by date, title etc.

This was only added a few months ago though, in [#3494](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms/pull/3494), so you'll have to [update to the latest version](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/releases/#update-the-cms-version) to get that feature.